# WooCommerce: Get newest products and sort them (partially) randomly

Tags: php, wordpress, random, woocommerce, product

I want to get the last 20 posts (in my case WooCommerce products) and show 10 of them in a random order.

For now I get the new posts like this:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'                     => 'product',
    'orderby'                       => 'date',
    'order'                         => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page'                => 20,
);
```

I know that I could get the posts in random order like this:

```php
'orderby'                       => 'rand',
'posts_per_page'                => 10,
```

But how is it possible to combine these two?
w
Is there a way to store the posts from the first loop and use them in a second loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, this is one of them

- [wp_get_recent_posts( array $args = array(), string $output = ARRAY_A )](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/) - Retrieve a number of recent posts.
- [shuffle ( array &$array ) : bool](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) - This function shuffles (randomizes the order of the elements in) an array. It uses a pseudo random number generator that is not suitable for cryptographic purposes.
- [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) — Remove a portion of the array and replace it with something else

```php
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 20, // Number of recent posts
    'post_status' => 'publish', // Show only the published posts
    'post_type'   => 'product'
));

// array_splice ( array, offset, length )
$sub = array_splice( $recent_posts, 10, 10 );

// Random
shuffle( $sub );

array_splice( $recent_posts, 10, 0, $sub );

// Loop
foreach( $recent_posts as $post ) {
    echo $post['ID'] . '<br>';
    //echo '<pre>', print_r( $post, 1), '</pre>';
}

wp_reset_query();
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I forgot to mention that I want to show only 10 of the 20 posts in a random order. That's why I thought about a second loop.

Comment: answer updated, for your additional question you can use [`array_splice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)